# Videos on my website Monsterfilms.com are not playing on Apple devices. Why?

Tags: ios, html5-video

I'm using django and so my templates look like this:

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="{{page.image.url}}" id="bgvid">
    <source src="{{page.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The videos work fine on Linux and Microsoft but are not working on Apple devices.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is rather mundane.  I've tried using different video editing software to render the videos to h.264 codec and it now works.  It seems the software I was using is not doing something right for Apple?

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving the video files? If you are using Django's built in server you will find that the videos will not load due to Django's server does not support byte range requests. See this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/NZ1qTkZ6vok/fhdz7rTtL1EJ

And this ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22479